# irreducibility of multivariate integral polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $f$ be a polynomial in the variables $x_1, \ldots, x_n$, where $n > 1$, and with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Are there convenient assumptions on $f$ to make the following implication? Assume that $f$ is irreducible in the ring ${\mathbb Z}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$, then $f$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$.

For instance, if $n = 1$, you would require that the leading coefficient of $f$ is equal to $1$ (Gauss lemma). Are you aware of a similar condition in case $n > 1$ ? Thank you.